# Why does my gRPC pod in GCP GKE result in a 502?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

I have a pod in GKE with a container that listens on two ports. One accepts http requests and one is a gRPC endpoint. I have these annotations on the K8S service:

```
cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"grpc":"HTTP2"}'
cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true, "exposed_ports": {"9520":{}}}'
cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"grpc":"api-grpc-backend"}}'
```

As far as I know, the annotations are supposed to point the gRPC port to a custom health check and set the protocol between the GCP LB and the gRPC backend to HTTP2.

I have this custom backend health check, to force the health check for the gRPC endpoint to listen for health on the http endpoint instead:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: api-grpc-backend
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 15
    port: 8000
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /health
```

The gRPC backend is passing its health check, and the backend shows healthy in GCP:

[image]

However, attempting to hit the endpoint with grpcurl returns `unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 502 (Bad Gateway); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

you might want to take a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-recipes/tree/main/ingress/single-cluster/ingress-custom-grpc-health-check) where it shows the limitation of gRPC protocol in health check is not supported, while  HTTP-like health checking is supported. There are two options for this scenario.

Run a proxy on a separate port that translates HTTP health check requests into gRPC and then forwards the transformed request to the application port that serves a gRPC health check.
Run a dedicated health checker on a separate port that speaks HTTP. This health checker responds to health check requests directly rather than proxying them.

For http to proxied health check:

```
$ grpc_health_proxy --http-listen-addr localhost:8080 \
                    --http-listen-path /healthz \
                    --grpcaddr localhost:50051 \
                    --service-name echo.EchoServer --logtostderr=1 -v 1
```

For non proxied health check

```
spec:
 containers:
 - name: esp
   image: gcr.io/myrepo/healthchecker
   ports:
   - containerPort: 8081
 - name: grpcapp
   image: gcr.io/mygcr/myapp
   ports:
   - containerPort: 8080
```

The documentation provides yaml configuration for this setup and describing nuances in the configuration when using InstanceGroup backends or NetworkEndpointGroup (NEG) backends.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Got it, I edit my answer. Thank you.